# Cannot assign new value to array element - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, scope

I am relatively new to programming and I am new to javascript/html/css (read over a few tutorials) and am having a weird problem with my first script. (trying to make sudoku solver)
 the array puzzle contains: "3.542.81.4879.15.6.29.5637485.793.416132.8957.74.6528.2413.9.655.867.192.965124.8 " 
where puzzle[0] = 3  puzzle[ 1 ] = .    and so on.
puzzle represents an unsolved sudoku puzzle where digits 1-9 rep solved cells and . unsolved cells.
Below is my code for one of my functions and there are 4 alert messages in it. My problem lies near MESSAGE 4 where `puzzle[c+(9*r)] = nums[0];` shows that `puzzle[c+9*r]` still contains a . and not the value of num[0] (in the first case 6). 
Declared outside of functions:

```
var puzzle = new Array();
var options = new Array();
var nums = new Array();
var r = 0;
var c = 0;
var num=0;
```

- function checkNumber works fine *
- MESSAGE 1:  "puz conatians ."
- MESSAGE 2: "nums length is 1"
- MESSAGE 3: "nums[0] is 6"
- MESSAGE 4: = "puzzle is ." SHOULD BE "puzzle is 6"

Any help would be much appreciated! Please let me know if I need to further clarify something =]

```
function makeOptionsArray() {

    // loop through 9x9 grid of sudoku r = row c = column
    for (r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            nums.length = 0; // reset array for each new cell

            if (puzzle[c + (9 * r)] == '.') { // if unknown cell
                alert("puz contains " + puzzle[c + 9 * r]); // MESSAGE 1
                for (num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
                    if (checkNumber(num, r, c)) { // check digits 1-9


                        nums.push(num); // keep track of possible values 
                        //for this cell based on other known values on the board


                    }
                }
                options[c + (9 * r)] = nums; // used for another part & will contain all possible values for an unsolved cell
                alert("nums length is " + nums.length); // MESSAGE 2       
                if (nums.length == 1) { // if only 1 possible number add to sudoku
                    alert("nums[0] is " + nums[0]); // MESSAGE 3
                    puzzle[c + (9 * r)] = nums[0];
                    document.getElementById(c + 9 * r).innerHTML = nums[0];
                    alert("puzzle is " + puzzle[c + 9 * r]); //MESSAGE 4
                    makeOptionsArray(); // call function again with updated puzzle (one less unknown cell) 
                }
                if (nums.length == 0) { //if no possible options then no solutions for puzzle
                    alert("No solutions");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your local variables with `var`.  I don't know that that's the problem here, but get in the habit.

Comment: I don't believe I use any local variables here.

Comment: Is there a difference caused by accessing `puzzle[c + (9 * r)]` in one place and accessing it without brackets in the next instance - `puzzle[c + 9 * r]`?

Comment: nope, I initially thought so too, but turns out to make no difference!

Comment: @Neel ah OK, I see. Well, those loop iterator variables probably *should* be local to the function.

Comment: Is it possible that when you do `document.getElementById(c + 9 * r).innerHTML = nums[0];` that you have an event handler that reacts on that element changing?  Perhaps as soon as you run that statement, it is re-setting your `puzzle[c+9*r]` value back to `.`?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the problem; I just commented it out and ran it- same story as before.

Comment: @Houdmont—the `*` operator is applied before the `+` operator so the result of `c + (9 * r)` is identical to `c + 9 * r`.